# Define a Sigmoid relation between two variables

Tags: linear-transformations, logistic-regression

I have the variable A: 'Probability of X' which takes the range [0, 1]. I need to define a second variable B: 'Risk rate' with range [0, 1] as a function of A. The requirements are:

- If A = 0 then B = 0,
- If A = max(A) then B = 1
- They must follow a classic Sigmoid function.

I would really appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Because, I need to assume that risk rate values will be very close to 1 and 0.

Comment: you mean like $B=\dfrac{6A^2}{1+5A^2}$?

Comment: My fault, max(A) is a value between 0 and 1. So, max(A) must map to B=1. I will edit the question immediately.